# yii2 Modal window loads partially

Tags: forms, yii2, modal-dialog

error generated: TypeError: context is undefined

i need help to load html page retrieved by jquery to a modal. Console log prints the retrieved page but i cant load the contents  [of form loaded via jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP1RH.jpg) into the modal. I guess the problem is in the jquery code below here

```
            $('#modal').modal({show:true})  //show:true
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).html(result)); //probable error



Modal::begin([
'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
'id' => 'modal',
'size' => 'modal-lg',
'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => FALSE]
]);

    //grid view
[
    'attribute' =>'client_id',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
        return Html::a($model->staff->name, ['payments/create'], ['class'=>"popupModal","data-key"=>$model->id]);               
    },
],


$('.popupModal').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('data-key');
    //load ajax and show model 
    dataObj = {'job':id};
    $.ajax({
        url         : '" . Url::toRoute(["payments/create"]). "',
        type        :'get',
        data        :dataObj,
        dataType    :'html', 
        success:function(data){
            $('#modal').modal({show:true})
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr(data));
        },
    })
    .fail (function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.dir(xhr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<?php
  Modal::begin([
     'header' =>'<h4>Ficha</h4>',
     'id'     =>'modal',
     'size'   =>'modal-lg',
     'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => FALSE]
   ]);

  echo "<div id="modalContent"> </div>";

  Modal::end();

?>
```